# How to make a Android client request secure?

Tags: android, security

I have a android application which sends updates about the purchases for the server. What I do now is, I encrypt the purchases and some other shared details into MD5, using the same key generator in server side and Android Client side. But if some one decode the APK file that person can easily make the calls by generating keys. What is the best way to prevent these kinds of attacks?

Comment: md5 is not reversible, it is a hash algorithm. with it you can verify integrity, at best.

Comment: one thing you can do is obtain a cipher key from your server after installation.

Comment: Maybe you can transfer your date over https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTTPS to communicate with you server in order to protect data in transit. Do not try to invent a secure protocol. If you want to restrict access to server API's use some form of authentication: username and password (over HTTPS) or better yet some sort of authentication token (OAuth, etc.). If you store keys and/or passwords inside the APK, anyone can extract them by decompiling the APK. If you want to protect against this, you need to use token authentication where tokens expire and can be invalidated if compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution is that you implement some web service which will return you a access key(will change every time you want to get access key) which you will use every time to communicate with your server in POST method. This is most secure method and being used by every good sites like Facebook, Twitter etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sine my problem was basically about updating the server with in-app purchases, I ended up doing Public/Private key authentication at the server end. Android suggest to verify receipts on client, but we just forward the receipts to server and did validation there using the public key.